# Pasting multiple fields into one field

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

In LibreOffice Calc when I try to copy multiple fields from one column and paste them elsewhere, instead of pasting multiple fields -> multiple fields all my data is pasted into one field with spaces in between.

On the image below I selected fields A1, A2, A3 and wanted to copy them into A5 - A7. Instead, it results in all data of the fields being pasted into A5.

How can I fix this?

Edit: the first time I paste the copied fields they actually get pasted normally, into multiple rows. Every next copy-paste results in them being put into one field.

[image: SO54752582 question example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it in the end.

The clipboard was clearly the problem. Just checked each software/extension that I have, that could influence my clipboard behavior.

I think it most likely was a plugin for Anki flashcards software, where it would create new flashcards automatically if I had the correct format of data in my clipboard: https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/17496... After closing Anki, things seem to have returned to normal. Not 100% sure though. I had Parcellite installed too, but not running at the time. Uninstalled it around the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Copied with <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and pasted (into A5 for example) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> works reliably for me (5.4.3.2).

Comment: Thanks! I found the solution. The clipboard was the problem.